# Codeception does not find element by selector

Tags: php, codeception

I am working on CMS (PHPShop) what use WINDOWS-1251 (Cyrillic - I think it might be the reason of trouble) 
I wrote symple test on page.
Like so

```
        $I->see('Пожалуйста, оплатите свой заказ');
        $I->see('Оплатить заказ №');
        $I->seeElement('div', ['class' => 'order']);
        $I->seeElement('input', ['name' => 'token']); // here is the failer
        /**
         * Element located either by name, CSS or XPath element with input' with attribute(s) '"name":"token" was not found.
         */
```

If I do search on the page I can find this input with name "token" but test failed. I afraid it because not Unicode encoding problem am I right?

[Here link to the page](https://github.com/Legion112/codeception-toable-php-shop/blob/master/FirstCest.tryToTest.fail.html)

Comment: Have you saved your test file as Windows-1251 too?

Comment: @Naktibalda all project in the same encode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in ajax. This content was dynamically added to DOM so the Codeception can't find those element on the page.

I really hate any CMS with magic and mess...